# How to list object key names with jsonpath?

Tags: json, node.js, jsonpath

I am using [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) with [jsonpath](http://npmjs.org/package/JSONPath).
I have this json structure:

```
{
  things:{
    books: [
      {name: "book1"},
      {name: "book2"},
      {name: "book3"},
      {name: "book4"},
    ],
    movies: [
      {name: "movie1"},
      {name: "movie2"},
      {name: "movie3"},
      {name: "movie4"},
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to know the jsonpath expression that returns an array with the key names of the `things` object. That would be:

```
["books","movies"]
```

For now, I am doing this:

```
Object.keys(jsonpath.eval(jsonStructure,"$.things").pop());
```

But I don't find it elegant... I should not need to get a copy the whole structure when I only need the key names.

Comment: Why use JSONPath when you can just do `Object.keys(jsonStructure.things)`?

Comment: True, that would also work. But my point is to do it only with jsonpath. The idea is that the jsonpath strings will be stored in a config file. I would like to be able to affect the script behavior only changing the config file and not the code.

Answer (score 12):

jsonPath has new update jsonpath-plus
jsonpath-plus expands on the original specification to add some additional operators and makes explicit some behaviors the original did not spell out.

`^` for grabbing the parent of a matching item
`~` for grabbing property names of matching items (as array)

so to get proper output use this query `things.*~`
you can try here also https://jsonpath.com/

Comment: that's perfect!

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a better solution than your own:

```
Object.keys(jsonpath.eval(jsonStructure,"$.things").pop());
```

I think the main misconception here is that you don't have to worry about this snippet "getting a copy of the whole structure", because you aren't copying the whole structure.  You already have the entire object loaded into memory, jsonpath doesn't create a new copy, it simply returns a reference to the already existing object, i.e.:

```
jsonpath.eval(jsonStructure,"$.things").pop() === jsonStructure.things //true
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but might still be relevant.

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for this kind of task as it is much better suited for data processing and analyzing. Once you wrap your head around it that is (:

Anyways, here is how you could answer your question if you are willing to add another dependency

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { things: { books: [ { name: 'book1' }, { name: 'book2' }, { name: 'book3' }, { name: 'book4' } ], movies: [ { name: 'movie1' }, { name: 'movie2' }, { name: 'movie3' }, { name: 'movie4' } ] } };

console.log(objectScan(['things.*'], { rtn: 'property' })(data));
// => [ 'movies', 'books' ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score -1):

The syntax you used for give is wrong
to get keys in json path use **"$.*~"**
ex.
**input**:
{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName" : "doe",
"age"      : 26
}
**output**:
[
"firstName",
"lastName",
"age"
]

Comment: Is it meant to be a new answer? Or a comment on another answer? You can [edit your previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58959850/edit) if you want to add more details.